# Problems with nested JSON

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, nested, gson

What did we do?
We are working on an Exam with an Movie API and we are getting JSON back. We tried manually to extract the 'inner' JSON part an our Method is working well. We are getting all Data right. We converted it with GSON.
But its a nested JSON. We´ve tried several methods from here and other sources as well for nested JSON. We just want to get the "results" part out of it. Whats wrong with our Code? 
It may be just a little Mistake but we can´t figure it out.

```
    public void test() {
        int status = 0;
        String inputLine = "";
        System.out.println("Test Methode");
        try {
            String name = " The Italien Job";

            URL url = new URL("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?"
                    + "api_key=/Notforyou:D/language=en-US&"
                    + "query=Spirited%20Away&page=1&include_adult=false");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            status = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Status " + status);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
                System.out.println("Ausgabe 1 " + inputLine);
                if (status == 200) {
                    System.out.println("Ausgabe 2 " + inputLine);
                    //Gson gson = new Gson();
                    //List<Film> filme = gson.fromJson(inputLine.toString(), List.class);


                    Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Film>>(){}.getType();
                    List<Film> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(inputLine, listType);

                    System.out.println("Anzahl Filme " + yourClassList.size());
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Fehler in dem Request");
                }
            }
            in.close();
            con.disconnect();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(theMovieDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(theMovieDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

Edit: the Json. we want the inner part. After the "results". Please ignore the quotation marks. I just typed it in fast.

```
{
„page“ : 1,
„total_results“:1,
„total_pages“:1,
„results“:[
    {
    „vote_count“:5511,
    „id“:129,
    „video“: false,
    „vote_average“:8.5,
    „title“:"Spirited Away",
    „popularity“: 24.739224,
    „original_language“:“ja“,
    „release_date“: „2001-07-20“
    }
    ]
}
```

I hope somebody can help.
Thanks ^^

Comment: What is the JSON you are trying to parse? What is a "nested" JSON? And ... Please make a [mcve].

Comment: Are you having trouble getting the data with an HttpURLConnection? If not, all that code is completely irrelevant to your question. The only thing that is relevant is the JSON you're trying to parse, and how you're trying to parse it. Why do you accumulate the lines into `content`, but also try to parse one single `inputLine` by itself? Does the API return multiple JSON objects, one per line? If not, that cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: (Not that it matters, but there's no reason to use a StringBuffer here instead of a StringBuilder.)

Comment: How did that question get an upvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get *results* JSONArray from JSON response which is having all the films and further need to convert it to a list of films.

It can be achieved using below code:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (new JsonParser())
            .parse(content.toString().trim()).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray films = ((JsonArray) jsonObject.get("results"));
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Film>>(){}.getType(); 
List<Film> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(films, listType);
```